# How to call non-form elements within a form tag

Tags: javascript, forms

given the following markup:

```
<form>
    <p>Example text.</p>
    <label>My Label</label>
    <input type="text">
</form>
```

. . . how would I get the p element from the form HTMLCollection.  For example:

```
<script>
    var myForm = document.getElementsbyTagName('form')[0];
    console.log(myForm[0]);
</script>
```

This code returns the input element, and not the paragraph.  so, how would I grab the paragraph?

Comment: Pure js kind of sucks for this... you have to get elements by tag, then compare their parent tag to match the "form" tag. Interested in a jQuery solution? Also... why not give them an id or class? And select by id or class?

Comment: @zozo: You mean "pure DOM", not "pure JS". And it's not really all that bad.

Comment: @ CallMeMisterX: You don't "call" elements. You "search for" them, "refer to" them, "get" them, etc. You "call" functions or methods.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder I said "kind of sucks" not "sucks" :).

Comment: @CallMeMisterX Quick question... you only need the "p"? Because title says something else. Getting the paragraph is simple - you have 2 answers below.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `getElementsByTagName` on the form as well:

```
// Get the first paragraph element, if any
var p = myForm.getElementsByTagName('p')[0];
```

On [modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector), you can use `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll` to use just about any CSS expression:

```
// Get the first paragraph element, if any
var p = myForm.querySelector('p');
```

`querySelector` finds the first matching element. `querySelectorAll` returns a static list of matching elements.

Answer (score 0):

`myForm.childNodes[1]` will return `<p>Example text.</p>`:

```
var myForm = document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0];
console.log(myForm.childNodes[1]);
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/v8J9h/)**

Comment: **Wow** is that delicate, though. Simply removing the whitespace between `<form>` and `<p>` breaks it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - yup, but it's specifically for this question, not a catch all for every scenario.